# Comparing two views

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, view

I current have two views that are pulling in different results. 
One is in the old database and the other is in the new.
the ond view pulls in ~50000 records whereas the new view is pulling in ~40000
Both have almost all the same data except for one or two columns.

Is there a way where I can combine the two and see what is different?

I have limit knowledge when it comes to queries and joins.

I tried left joining and right joining but it is giving me 100000+ results.  I dont want that.  I want ~50000 results and have the columns null where there is no info.

Is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following. First you join the tables with a left join, and later you filter the null values from the new.

something like this

```
select  *
from    oldview o
        left join newview n
          on  o.field = n.field
where   n.value is null
```

That way you combine them, and have the newview values filtered with the where statement. The thing is, you first combine them, and afterwards you filter them.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
    SELECT * FROM OldView
EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM NewView
```

Comment: I have one column that is named different things on both tables and want to have those columns side by side.  This proves to be a problem since it keeps telling me that one of the columns in invalid and vice versa with the next view.  Is there a waya round this? thanks!

Comment: All of the result columns of a View must have unique names.  so you will have to rename the column(s) using "As", like `, OldView.Col1 As oldCol1, `.